# UTF 16 code for a degree symbol

Tags: utf-16

I need to put a degree symbol on my html page. It will be read from a property file. So I need to figure out the UTF-16 encoding for a degree symbol as superscript.
What is the UTF-16 for something like N* where N is a random number and * is supposed to be the symbol

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm

Comment: Thank you. Please post as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find all the data you need [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm). In particular you can use `&deg;` to embed degree sign in your html page.